# Matplotlib wont join data points when the x axis isn't equally spaced

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My real data has thousands of data points so I'm currently using a small array to test things with.

I'm trying to get rid of the zeros in the y axis data and plot the non zero values against the relevant indices from the x axis data. I can see I'm getting the I'm getting the right numbers in my new arrays, but my graph is blank.

Output of my array prints:

```
[array([ 1,  6, 54,  4,  2,  3,  8])]

[array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 11])]
```

It works if I plot the original data, (working being the points are all joined up with lines). Also If I add '.' to the plot command I get dots where the points are meant to be, but I cannot get the data points joined up. I think this may be because my new x axis data is not continuous, but I'm not sure.

```
y1 = np.array([1,0,6,54,4,2,0,0,3,0,8])
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
yind = y1.nonzero()
y2 = []
x2 = []

for el in yind:
    y2.append(y1[el]) 
    x2.append(x1[el])

print y2
print x2
pl.plot(x2,y2)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do:

```
plt.plot(x2[0],y2[0])
```

Because

```
>>> x2
[array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 11])]
>>> y2
[array([ 1,  6, 54,  4,  2,  3,  8])]
```

and when you see the `Type` of `x2` and `y2` you see:

```
>>> type(y2)
<class 'list'>
```

but `x2[0]` and `y2[0]` is the array you want to plot:

```
>>> x2[0]
array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 11])
>>> y2[0]
array([ 1,  6, 54,  4,  2,  3,  8])
>>> type(y2[0])
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, is that needed because nonzero returns a tuple?

Comment: check the edited answer. If it works, do accept it as the answer

Comment: It works, I didn't notice the square brackets around the array.